# center align textarea in JavaFX with CSS

Tags: javafx, javafx-css, javafx-textarea

I know I am supposed to set `-fx-text-alignment: center;` in order to achieve a center-aligned textarea.

```
#txtFaContent
{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

with `txtFaContent` being the ID of my textarea (as well as its variable name inside the controller). But it doesn't have any effect on the text alignment of my textarea (I played with right/left/center; but no success).

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style class in your TextArea.text:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.getStyleClass().add("centered-text-area");
```

Add ***.text*** in your CSS:

```
.centered-text-area .text {
  -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Comment: is "text" a substructure of textarea? I couldn't find it in the Oracle's CSS reference guide.

Comment: TextArea has all properties of TextInputControl and lot of inherited properties of other controls. Please see CSS Reference > Inheritance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area

Comment: I've been reading that reference all the day. But sorry, I can't still understand how that ".text" is related to text-area. I know a TextArea inherits from other Classes (TextInputControl, ScrolPane, Region, Pane, Node and Parent); but none of these classes has anything to do with the class Text! That's my problem

Comment: Inheritance in CSS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance


"CSS also provides for certain properties to be inherited by default..." and
"The following properties inherit by default...": javafx.scene.Node, **javafx.scene.text.Text**, javafx.scene.text.Font.